# form validation CodeIgniter error

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

Anyone know about form validation in CI here ?
As long this script in my function, it will give error
I dont know why, I just copy paste from the user guide, and put it in my function

and also, I cant do autoload.php -> $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');

and this is the code for form validation :

```
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('item_name', 'Item Name', 'is_numeric|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('item_price', 'Item Price', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('item_description', 'Item Description', 'required');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
  $this->create();
}else{
    $this->load->view('formsuccess');
}
```

please help me guys..

[first error of form validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTOPC.png)

[second error of form validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doe27.png)

complete code :

```
function submit(){

  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->load->helper('form', 'url');


  $this->form_validation->set_rules('item_name', 'Item Name', 'is_numeric|required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('item_price', 'Item Price', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('item_description', 'Item Description', 'required');


  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
  {
  $this->create();
   }
     else
     {
   $this->load->view('formsuccess');
     }
}
```

Comment: autoload.php -> $autoload['libraries'] = array('database'); if its only database, its no error

Comment: what is the error message that you are getting.

Comment: if you want to autoload libraries go application/config/autoload.php and set there.

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: template::$load

Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php

Line Number: 147

Comment: second error is this :
Fatal error: Call to a member function helper() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\system\libraries\Form_validation.php on line 147
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function helper() on null

Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php

Comment: you can auto load it by autoload.php -> $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session','form_validation');

Comment: Can you add your view to you question? click on the edit button to update question.

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshiVersion1.0 hi anmol, is this code you are saying ? $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session );

Comment: @Richo yeah there you set the database,session,form_validation

Comment: change this `$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));` to this `$this->load->helper('form', 'url');`

Comment: @Richo check above comment of mine

Comment: @Richo add complete code.

Comment: its still not working, @Abdulla :(  i changed the code already

Comment: @Richo man post complete code

Comment: Looks like your using HMVC Please show the full template.php file not if controller file should be upper case for first letter of class name and file name example `Template.php` and `class Template extends MX_Controller{}`

Comment: Have you tried placing the library in the __constructor() area http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#reserved-method-names what version of codeigniter you using?

Comment: @wolfgang1983 wow wolfgang, you are right, i forgot to use uppercase and MX controller, thankyou man :D sorry for the easy question, im only a newbie programmer

Comment: @wolfgang1983 im currently using CodeIgniter 3.0.2, is it better to use 2.x.x ?

Comment: Use latest one because HMVC will now work with CI2 versions now.

Comment: and there is no problem anymore,  with the autoload.php since i changed my template source code, thankyou for @wolfgang1983 and friends who help me here :)

Comment: Glad to know that.explain your solution in answer so it may be guide to newbies :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$this->load->model('login_database','file');

$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('item_name', 'Item Name', 'is_numeric|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('item_price', 'Item Price', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('item_description', 'Item Description', 'required');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
$this->load->view('formsuccess');
}else
{
$this->create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you using HMVC

dont forget to use MX_controller.

This is the full solution of my problem :

Looks like your using HMVC Please show the full template.php file not if controller file should be upper case for first letter of class name and file name example Template.php and class Template extends MX_Controller{}